# How do I use a C# library on a Raspberry?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

I have a C# file with math functions I need to use in a GUI on Raspberry Pi. The GUI is written with Python.

Today I managed to use pybind to create .so files from C and C++ code. That worked really well and I could create an executable package from a Python script for the Raspberry which compiled the functions from the .so

But how do I work with C# in this regard? Unfortunately I can't just use C because the C# functions all require the MathNet library. Is there a workaround for this?

Can I make a wrapper so that I can call the C# functions from C++ and then use pybind again to create a .so file and import them for Python?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: C# is not like C++, in that is requires a running C# VM (usually `dotnet`).

Comment: I removefd C++ and C from your tags. Since your question is only about C#

Comment: You don't just run a C# file, you need to compile it first (just like with C and C++), so what does that program compile to?

Comment: If you have a C# file, i understand that as you having the source code files (because C# is a source code language, not some type of .NET assembly, DLL, or other library file). Compile it to native code (it's called AOT compiling, modern C# build environments should be able to do it), and then you should be able (more or less) to use it similarily to .so files. For the methods written in C# that you wanto to call from Python, restrict yourself to simple/primitive data types for the method parameters and return values as not to make things unneccessarily complicated for you...

Comment: It is generally easier to stay within one language eco system. Isn't there a python lib that gives you the same feature set? Maybe a day spent on looking for one could save you weeks of tinkering a bridge.

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins You understand it correctly, I have the C# source code.  Thank you for the explanation and suggestion, I found some results on Google in this regard which I'll go through now. This seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: @Fildor It's about 1500 lines of matrix operations which I didn't want to rewrite for Python. But the more I research, the more it seems like that would be the easiest and most reasonable solution. There is nothing wrong with Python, I simply want to save my sanity and not have to "translate" so much code into a different language.

Comment: I didn't mean _you_ should port MathNet but  maybe there is some python lib already? A Quick shot gave me [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html). Did you have a look into that? I guess a language native solution will also be (probably) faster due to lack of overhead.

Comment: Did you compile using Core and download the Runtime Library : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: @Fildor See my update edit in the original question. I will be trying to use Native AOT for .NET 7 because this library is also used for other applications and the company I am working for wants to be able to update it easily.

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins Thank you very much for the suggestion, I updated the original post because of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to someone in the comments I was able to learn about Native AOT which comes with .NET 7. This allows you to compile C# class libraries into native code (results in .dll for Windows, .so for Linux) which can be used by programs written in other languages. I haven't implemented it yet but it certainly looks possible to do it this way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows#build-native-libraries